# Local invertibility of $f(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}x+2 x^{2} \sin \frac{1}{x} & \text { if } x \neq 0 \\ 0 & \text { if } x=0\end{array}\right.$

Tags: real-analysis

Q. Which of the following functions $f$ admit an inverse in an open neighbourhood of the point $f(p)^{?}$

1. For $p=(1,0)$ and $f(x, y)=\left(x^{3} \exp y+y-2 x, 2 x y+2 x\right)$
2. For $p=(1, \pi)$ and $f(r, \theta)=(r \cos \theta, r \sin \theta)$
3. For $p=0$ and $f(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}x+2 x^{2} \sin \frac{1}{x} & \text { if } x \neq 0 \\ 0 & \text { if } x=0\end{array}\right.$
4. For $p=0$ and $f(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}x^{2} \sin \frac{1}{x} & \text { if } x \neq 0 \\ 0 & \text { if } x=0\end{array}\right.$

Options $(1)$ and $(2)$ can be deal with inverse function theorem and $f$ in $(4)$ cannot be invertible in any neighbourhood of $0$ since $x=\frac{1}{n \pi},~~n \geq N$ for some $N \in \mathbb N$, lies inside. Now, what about $f$ in option $(3)$?

Comment: @Invisible does inverse function theorem gives us necessary and sufficient conditions for local invertibility?

Comment: It gives sufficient conditions. I haven't checked the continuity, so I deleted my comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint : Prove that in any neighborhood containing $0$ contains a local  extremum of $f$ and $f$ is not injective locally.

Comment: I am wondering is the following idea correct? I am just adding more details to your hint. At the end-points of each interval $[\frac{1}{\pi(n+1)},\frac{1}{\pi(n)}]$ the function $f'(x)$ have values of different sign and therefore $\exists u_n\in (\frac{1}{\pi(n+1)},\frac{1}{\pi(n)})$ such that $f'(u_n)=0$. One can check that $f''(u_n)\neq0$ and hence $u_n$ is the point of local extrema. But if $f$ is bijective on some nbhd of $0$, then it is monotonic there since $f$ is continuous.

Comment: Note that $u_n\to 0$ as $n\to \infty$. Also around each $u_n$ one can find a nbhd where it is not monotonic since $u_n$ is a local extrema. Is that correct? Thank you so much!